# Pomelo & EFCore not ignoring views in migrations

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-core, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I have a dotnet core project that uses EFCore and Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore. I've just updated from I think EFCore 3.1.0 to 5.0.7 (the latest at the time of writing this) and simultaneously Pomelo to 5.0.0

In my project, I use EFCore to call stored procedures and map them to views. I've added the views to the context as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<NameOfView>().HasNoKey().ToView(null);
```

What I've now noticed since updating EFCore and Pomelo is that whenever I try to run a migration, it no longer ignores these views. I keep getting `CreateTable` or `DropTable` scripts in the migration depending on whether the views are in the database snapshot. Before the update these views were simply ignored.

Is there some property I need to set for the views in the context to ensure that they are ignored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are experiencing the following EF Core 5.0 breaking change [ToView() is treated differently by migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/breaking-changes#toview-is-treated-differently-by-migrations), in particular the first migration after upgrade behavior explained here

> **New behavior**
>
> Now `ToView(string)` marks the entity type as not mapped to a table in addition to mapping it to a view. This results in the first migration after upgrading to EF Core 5 to try to drop the default table for this entity type as it's not longer ignored.

I could understand the reasoning for changing the fluent API behavior, but not the migration behavior (hello EF Core, backward compatibility?). And the suggested "mitigation"

> Use the following code to mark the mapped table as excluded from migrations:
>
> ```
> protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
> {
>    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("UserView", t => t.ExcludeFromMigrations());
> }
> ```

While it seems to fix the first migration after upgrade behavior, it requires specifying fake table name. And unfortunately `ToTable` method overload with `ExcludeFromMigrations` capability does not accept `null` table name.

The workaround I would suggest, which seems to be working for both exiting and new "unmapped" entities, is to replace

```
.ToView(null)
```

with

```
.HasAnnotation(RelationalAnnotationNames.IsTableExcludedFromMigrations, true)
```

Note: This is EF Core general issue, not database provider specific, hence has nothing to do with MySQL or Pomelo.

Comment: Interestingly, I am unable to replicate this issue, when creating a migration in 3.1 and then upgrading to 5.0 and creating another migration. I don't get _any_ operations generated for the second migration (assuming I don't change anything explicitly). What am I missing?

Comment: @lauxjpn You don't even need to switch to 3.x.  In 5.x create `class Foo { public int Bar { get; set; } }` and add `modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>().HasNoKey().ToView(null);`. Then add new migration.  It won't contain `Foo`. W/o changing anything, add second new migration. In the generated `Up` you'll see something like `DropTable("Foo")`

Comment: I see, it is a `ToView(null)` specific issue. A simple workaround is also to just name the views/stored procedures explicitly, e.g. `ToView("ExpiredIceCreams")`. Then add a migration and remove the unnecessary operations from the `Up()` and `Down()` methods. Future migrations will not add those operations again, because EF Core is now treating the views/stored procedures as views again.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to an issue with Pomelo or EF Core, since the following does work as expected:

1. Create a project with the following content:

**Project.csproj**:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>disable</Nullable>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="5.0.7">
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="5.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="5.0.7" />
        <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="5.0.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**Program.cs**:

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace IssueConsoleTemplate
{
    public class IceCream
    {
        public int IceCreamId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime BestServedBefore { get; set; }
    }

    public class ExpiredIceCream
    {
        public int IceCreamId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime BestServedBefore { get; set; }
        public int DaysExpired { get; set; }
    }

    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<IceCream> IceCreams { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ExpiredIceCream> ExpiredIceCreams { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                var connectionString = "server=127.0.0.1;port=3306;user=root;password=;database=So67919519_01";
                var serverVersion = ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString);
                optionsBuilder.UseMySql(connectionString, serverVersion)
                    .UseLoggerFactory(
                        LoggerFactory.Create(
                            configure => configure
                                .AddConsole()
                                .AddFilter(level => level >= LogLevel.Information)))
                    .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                    .EnableDetailedErrors();
            }
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<IceCream>()
                .HasData(
                    new IceCream {IceCreamId = 1, Name = "Vanilla", BestServedBefore = new DateTime(2021, 1, 1)},
                    new IceCream {IceCreamId = 2, Name = "Chocolate", BestServedBefore = new DateTime(2021, 5, 15)},
                    new IceCream {IceCreamId = 3, Name = "Matcha", BestServedBefore = DateTime.Today.AddYears(5)});

            modelBuilder.Entity<ExpiredIceCream>(
                entity =>
                {
                    entity.ToView("ExpiredIceCreams");
                    entity.HasNoKey();
                });
        }
    }

    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            using var context = new Context();

            var expiredIceCreams = context.ExpiredIceCreams.ToList();
            
            Trace.Assert(expiredIceCreams.Count == 2);
        }
    }
}
```

Create an initial migration:

```
dotnet ef migrations add Initial
```

Add the following code to the end of the `Up()` method in the generated `Migrations/..._Initial.cs` file:

```cs
migrationBuilder.Sql(@"
    CREATE VIEW `ExpiredIceCreams` AS
        SELECT *, DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), `BestServedBefore`) AS DaysExpired
        FROM `IceCreams`
        WHERE `BestServedBefore` <= CURDATE();");
```

Add the following code to the start of the `Down()` method in the generated `Migrations/..._Initial.cs` file:

```cs
migrationBuilder.Sql(@"DROP VIEW `ExpiredIceCreams`;");
```

Update your database:

```
dotnet ef database update
```

Run the project to ensure it works as expected.

Then add a second migration:

```
dotnet ef migrations add Second
```

Take a look at the generated `Migrations/..._Second.cs` file.
It should not contain any operations regarding your `ExpiredIceCreams` view.

---

#### Where to go from here

I would start by diffing the old and new `...<MigrationName>.Design.cs` files, to see what is going on.

Feel free to post your migration files content, so we can take a look at it.

(Maybe this is connected to some charset or collation issue/change.)

Comment: Hi @lauxjpn, The use case is different, and the strange migration behavior seems to be "expected" and "ok" by EF Core core system designers. Not for users though.